# What is a word for a "protégé" who doesn't realize he is a "protégé"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a younger person that is unknowingly receiving guidance from an older, wiser individual.

The older person could be considered a mentor, and looks upon the younger as his protégé, but the younger doesn't consider their relationship that way.

In his mind, it's just an older friend who shares his stories, and it doesn't necessarily occur to the younger that he is being taught anything, just casual conversations with a friend.

**EDIT**: Added the tag for a short phrase as well, and an example usage such as:

The wizard's **protégé** learns of Powers he never dreamed of.

Want to suggest that the protégé is not aware that he is a protégé.

Comment: May we expand that to a phrase rather than one word?

Comment: I would prefer a single word, but not sure that there is one. A phrase that isn't too long might work.

Comment: It's the requirement of incorporating blissful ignorance on the part of the younger person that's making your question somewhat of a challenge!  I'm going to give it more thought.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. [How do you want to use your word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Please edit your question.  You can add stuff at the tail end of your question, incorporating clarifications and bits of additional information, from the comments, and any additional material you think would be helpful, such as "Sentence words sentence words __________ (the new word will go here) sentence words."

Comment: @Helmar - And you waited one whole minute before concluding the OP would not realize the mistake?  Reminds me of the definition of a nanosecond: the amount of time between the red light turning green and the Long Islander behind you leaning on his horn.

Comment: @aparente001 it was the time I looked at it. I neither waited nor had a close look at the edit time, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an ***unwitting mentee***. It's two words, but I don't consider that a too long phrase. I think unwitting describes nicely the ignorance of the protégé and mentee is less official than protégé feels.

> *unwitting:* not aware of what is really happening  [- MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwitting)
>
> *mentee* : one who is being mentored :  protégé  [- MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mentee)

Comment: Google shows 437 hits for 'unwitting protégé' and 1 (soon 2) for your 'unwitting mentee'.

Comment: @Keepthesemind so neither is really established.

Comment: @Laetitia - Hmmm, I like that. You prompted me to look up some similar words (unknowing, unconscious, unaware, oblivious), but they all feel like the mentee is unknowing in general, not just about the mentee thing.

Comment: @Laetitia - Also think I like the sound of 'unwitting protégé' better. He may be ignorant of his protégé status, but his mentor is not. I'll have to think on this but I like this.

Comment: My objection to "mentee" is that the verb form is not "ment", it is "mentor". Parallel construction would direct mentor / mentoree.

Answer (score 0):

The younger person is in the *sphere of influence* of the older person.  (Of course the ages might not be different -- it might just be a matter of greater or lesser experience.)

If you provide a couple of example sentences, with blanks where the word should go, I might be able to improve on this.

**Edit:**

If we flip the point of view, it might be easier.

*protector*

In his naïveté, the one being protected doesn't know he's being protected.  But the one doing the protecting is very aware of this.

Comment: To use Laetitia's suggestion, something like: The wizard's unwitting protégé learns of Powers he never dreamed of.